# "mutable" variables in Python package?

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am coding a package in Python 3 and I wonder if there's any way to have its variables change after importing it. Something like this:

import package
-> package.stuff points to None

package.init("bar")
-> package.stuff now points to "bar"

so I would like to have an init() function in the package which initialises its contents.

I am sure this is possible, but what is the proper way to achieve this in Python 3 ?

Happy for any hint on this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably add something like this to your package:

```
stuff = None


def init(value):
    global stuff
    stuff = value
```

On the other hand, users of the package can simply write `package.stuff = value` instead.

Comment: this works ? Pretty stunned right now.. I thought global variables inside modules/packages were like "immutable"! Thx a lot